# Semantic-UI-React grid columns padding do not set columns inline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I wish to have, in one row inline, 3 columns, 1st - narrwow with arrow, 2nd - wide as free space left, 3rd - narrow with arrow. I am trying to do it by setting `width` properties for many ways and one of then, in theory, should work (see code example). Bot because of padding of each column, the last of them goes down.

How I can do it?

```
<div className="popular-tabs-scroller">
        <Grid columns="equal">
          <Grid.Column>{'<'}</Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={14}>Content</Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column>{'>'}</Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to correct import `semantic-ui-less` styles into the project, and correctly set alias to `theme.config` in webpack config .